# Knife Bootstrap for new node failing for proxy authentication

Tags: knife

I built a new Chef server environment with version chef-server-core-12.15.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Installed Chef DK chefdk-2.0.28-1.el6.x86_64.rpm in new node in order to use knife command, where I copied chef starter kit as well.
Upon bootstrap process getting below error and my proxy environment is blocking to download install.sh from omnibus.

Getting below error. Can anyone help me on this, how to provide proxy authentication information during bootstrap process. So that

```
[chefadm@Chefserver chef-repo]$ sudo knife bootstrap <FQDN-Node> --ssh-user chefadm --node-name Apache
Node Apache exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) y

Client Apache exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) y

Creating new client for Apache

Creating new node for Apache

Connecting to <FQDN-Node>

chefadm@<FQDN-Node>'s password:

<FQDN-Node> -----> Installing Chef Omnibus (-v 13)

<FQDN-Node> downloading https://omnitruck-direct.chef.io/chef/install.sh

<FQDN-Node>   to file /tmp/install.sh.20672/install.sh

<FQDN-Node> trying wget...

<FQDN-Node> trying curl...

<FQDN-Node> trying perl...

<FQDN-Node> trying python...

<FQDN-Node> /tmp/install.sh.20672/install.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
<FQDN-Node> /tmp/install.sh.20672/install.sh: line 1: `<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Authentication Proxy Login Page</TITLE><script language="JavaScript"><!-- Begin'
<FQDN-Node> Starting the first Chef Client run...

<FQDN-Node> sh: line 258: chef-client: command not found

[chefadm@Chefserver chef-repo]$
```

Comment: Have you read [chef proxy documentation](https://docs.chef.io/proxies.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Yes I verified with setting up proxy but still it is failing.
Is there any offline mode of setting up chef-client on target nodes instead of downloading from omnibus ?

Also how to define local repository in chef server, so that I don't want to communicate to internet everytime for package installation. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use custom [bootstrap templates `--bootstrap-template` or just a custom bootstrap command `--bootstrap-install-command`.](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html#options)